# ¿Cómo funciona JS Image Zoom con clases?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un listado de imagenes, a la cual le quiero agregar el efecto ***zoom on hover*** con la librería **JS IMAGE ZOOM**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/js-image-zoom@0.7.0/js-image-zoom.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

Código HTML

```
<div class="img-container" style="width: 400px">
    <img src="https://github.com/malaman/js-image-zoom/blob/master/example/1.jpg raw=true"/>
</div>
<div id="img-container" style="width: 400px">
    <img src="https://github.com/malaman/js-image-zoom/blob/master/example/1.jpg raw=true" />
</div>
```

Código JS

```
var options1 = {
    width: 400,
    zoomWidth: 500,
    offset: {vertical: 0, horizontal: 10},
};
new ImageZoom(document.getElementById("img-container"), options1);
```

Ahora bien, funciona perfectamente pero el problema es que solo por ID (por obvias razónes no se puede repetir) con document.getElementById() pero al momento de hacerlo con document.getElementsByClassName() (para que tome todas las imagenes con esa clase) deja de funcionar.

Comment: Y que te impide usar simplemente CSS ? Es más fácil, menos librería, y la misma función ...?

Comment: Honestamente no conozco mucho de forma nativa, se me hizo sencillo usar una librería

Comment: Exactamente para hacer zoom una imagen, se necesita solamente una línea de código de css. En realidad

Comment: ¿Podrías comentar cuál es o dejar tu ejemplo? ¡Por favor!

Comment: `.img-container:hover img { transform: scale(1.5)`. Aunque esto funcione, hay que arreglar algunas cosas

Comment: Ya entendí tu punto con transform scale de CSS, es rápido no diré que no, pero quiero algo un poco más estético

Comment: Si entiendo, pero para obtener más efectos, requiere más css. Es todo

Comment: CSS era solo una opción

Comment: Sí, me agrada, no esta mal, te digo no conozco tan de manera nativa, hace muy bien el scale, pero me agrada el efecto draggable en la imagen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalmente cuando en estas librerias te piden ingresar eso: document.getElementById("img-container"), lo que te están pidiendo es el elemento en cuestión, no el ID. Por lo que haciendo un querySelectorAll no deberias tener problemas

```
var options1 = {
    width: 400,
    zoomWidth: 500,
    offset: {vertical: 0, horizontal: 10},
};
document.querySelectorAll(".img-container").forEach(e =>{
   new ImageZoom(e, options1);
});
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias!